# Failed To Resolve : com.github

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Everything was working fine, Then I tried adding some social login helper library and faced this issue for the first time, Then I removed it back and the issue is still there.

Every dependency from google or android working fine.

But every dependency which starts with com.github fails.

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application_id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 14
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.0@aar"
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.0.0@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.vanniktech:emoji-twitter:0.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.jaychang0917:SimpleAuth:{latest_version}'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project gradle,

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})

        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Dependency like Glide were working fine. Just restarted my android studio and facing same issues with them.

Need Help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never come across this syntax

`compile 'com.github.jaychang0917:SimpleAuth:{latest_version}'`

so I think it's wrong, you want to replace that `{}` with the actual version, I imagine it was just there as an example in the README. try:

`compile 'com.github.jaychang0917:SimpleAuth:1.0.5'`

(Reference https://github.com/jaychang0917/SimpleAuth/releases)

Comment: Now it's showing error for that specific library. Can you tell me where is the issue?

Comment: I just fixed your issue - now you have a new issue & new question :-)

Comment: Ohkay then. I will repost ;_;